# submit form with enter key that has button in it

Tags: jquery, html, forms, button, enter

I need to submit the form with the enter key, but it is not like the other questions in this website in my case. I do not have a `input[type="submit"]`, but I have a button (`<button id=""></button>`).

The full code of my form:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/my_script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<form id="myForm" action="userInfo.php" method="post">
<textarea name="mesazhi" cols="35" rows="4"></textarea>
<?php $idiperdoruesit = $_SESSION['id']; ?>
<input type="hidden" name="idiperdoruesit" value="<?php echo $idiperdoruesit; ?>" />
<br /><button id="sub" style="border-radius:0px; border-size:2px; border-style:solid; border-color:#ffffff; border-width:thin; background-color:#000000; color:#ffffff; height:26px; width:60px;  font-size:16px;">Send</button>
</form>
```

When the user clicks the button Send, then a jquery function sends the message to the database without reloading the page. Below is the jquery function:

```
$("#sub").click( function() {
 $.post( $("#myForm").attr("action"), 
         $("#myForm :input").serializeArray(), 
         function(info){ $("#result").html(info); 
   });
 clearInput();
});

$("#myForm").submit( function() {
  return false; 
});

function clearInput() {
    $("#myForm :input").each( function() {
       $(this).val('');
    });
}
```

How can I make to send the message by pressing the enter key?

Comment: So why are you using a button at all?

Comment: Use onkeypress event??

Comment: That *"duplicate"* has nothing to do with this question...

Comment: Note that a `<button>` can be used to submit forms directly: `<button type=submit>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the form's submit event, the default behavior of a form is to submit either when the submit button is clicked, or the enter key is pressed on a form input.

```
$("#myForm").submit(function(){
    $.post( $("#myForm").attr("action"), 
         $("#myForm :input").serializeArray(), 
         function(info){ $("#result").html(info); }
    );
    clearInput();
    return false;
});
```

now make your button a submit button and get rid of the click event. Now, when you press enter in any input other than a textarea, the form will submit and your handler will be called. No need for keydown event handlers and click handlers.

Comment: I don't understand why people are so insistent on using click events for form handling...

Comment: If I am not mistaken to validate a form with a submit button, the submit button must be inside the form tag. But some time you need to place the button somewhere else and now it wont submit anything. so this is why people use regular button

Comment: So, have said regular button trigger the submit event. Or make it part of the form using the form attribute. That clearly isn't the case in this question anyway.

Comment: Is'nt it what I just said? And yes, he could use the form attribute to make it submit the form but what if there is multiple submit button for the same form that are'nt in the form tag then It is more complicated. What I want to say is that it is'nt our role to judge what code he use, The "Best" solution might not be adapte to its application. We dont have all the info or the context in which he build his application.

Comment: The form is right there in his question. If he were to use click events rather than form events, he'd be able to simplify his code by removing the form completely because he isn't using it's functionality at all.

Comment: If he is like me He probably hide all the stuff that is'nt needed for the question. Has I said we dont always have all the code or context in which the said application is build

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `keydown` handler to do this. The return key is key 13.

```
$('input').on( 'keydown', function( e ) {
  if( e.which == 13 ) {
    tickleAPolarBear();
    //or something like $('#myForm').submit();
  }
} );
```

See [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/keydown) for more information about the keydown event.

Comment: tickleAPolarBear(LeftHand, RightHand){return null;}